# How send huge datapool in response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new in **node.js** ecosystem and need some help.

I have controller which triggered when user call URL.

```
async function get_all_information(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let start_date = req.query.start_date;
        let end_date = req.query.end_date;

        const binds = {};
        binds.start_date = start_date;
        binds.end_date = end_date;

        let query = `SOME LONG SQL STATEMENT`;

        await pool.query(query, binds, function (error, results) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log(results); // ~ 10 seconds

            res.send(JSON.stringify(results)); // ~ 15 seconds
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

I tried to use this code but faced the problem. Monthly datapool which return a database has `227011 rows`. It seems like `stringify` method create too huge JSON file. The Postman application just crash when I tried to test. I tried to analyze and notice that daily datapool create ~ 13 MB JSON file. We can say that monthly datapool could create ~ 400 MB JSON file.

Then I tried to streaming query rows like that:

```
pool.query('HUGE SQL QUERY').stream({ highWaterMark: 5 }).pipe(res);
```

Unfortunatly such code raise error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
```

Can someone show me how correctly send huge data from MySQL database in response?

---

@akram I used `fs` package as you adviced. I use next code to create JSON file:

```
await pool.query(sql_statement, binds, function (error, results) {
    if (error) throw error;
    fs.writeFile("information.json", results, 'utf8', function (error) {
        if(error) throw error;
    });
});
```

This code create json file which has ~ 3.5 MB size for monthly datapool. In editor I have next message:

```
This document contains very long lines. Soft wraps were forcibly enable to improve editor performance.
```

Also that json file contains:
[image]

It seems to me too strange.

Comment: You download a file and let the browser handle it.

Comment: IMO best way to send huge data is not to send it, but to change the business logic of your application. Do not bother browsers with gigabytes of data - better process it on server (DataBase server will be the best solution rather than Node.js) and push only pivot data for visualization

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought about using `cron` to create `*.json.gz` static file. The problem is that MySQL table which I use has 20 million records and every hour replenished with new ones. Also we don't know what period the user will choose. We'll have to do a recount every time. So in my case it's not solution.

Comment: @grapes actually there is no calculations on the node.js side. I just need to take monthly datapool from mysql table and show it on the map. MySQL return me 227011 rows (monthly datapool) in several seconds cause I use index and partitioning. I assure you, business logic is fine. Do you have any other ideas my friend? :)

Comment: If there is no way for reducing the dataset, sent to client, why not optimize it? Thought about changing json->csv? It will not only reduce the size at least by 2, but also allow streaming (means you can process line by line on client side, without getting full text in memory and parsing it).

Another idea - to make use of web socket protocol instead of http. In context of streaming data

Comment: You can create a file whenever you want.

Comment: @grapes it's really good idea. I also thought about your first your idea. I found [csv-stringifier][https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stringify] package which I tried to use like that: `pool.query('HUGE SQL QUERY').stream().pipe(stringify()).pipe(res);` Unfortunately next code return strange result. It return raw data, not structured, not like in JSON. Also encoding problems. Do you work with that package before?

Comment: No man, I didnt. You think there is a need for special package to stringify to csv? About encoding - always convert to utf-8 unless your language is not specific (like chinese e.g.) and utf-16/32 gives you better results for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSONStream  https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream, i think can resolve your issue, there is a lof of example in doc of JSONStream

Comment: I am little bit confused. In documentation all examples parse ready JSON file. In my case I don't have JSON file. I just got the data from the database. Can you show me little example please?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, add our result to file  fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', results); after reader myjsonfile.json by jsonStream

Comment: Can you check my post again please?  I used `fs` package as you adviced. I notice some strange behavior.